# Powerbuilder - Trying to importString a long string with a single double quote (")

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

```
importstring(ls_string)
```

The string is a tab delimited text that has a single quote. This single quote is causing an error when the string is imported into the DataWindow.

I tried to replace all occurrences of double quote with `~"`or `\"` but both do not work.

What do you think is a potential work around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The datawindow escape character for a single quote (') is three tilde characters and then the single quote (which escapes the single quote as well as the tilde itself).

This makes the entry [O'Connor] look like [O~~~'Connor].

In the PB help this is under the heading: 'Nested strings and special characters for DataWindow object properties'